# Create complex Custom adapters Moshi

Tags: java, android, kotlin, moshi

I am making a call to a service with retrofit and the response that is a JSON I am trying to deal with Moshi, but I don't know how to define the adapters since my data model is somewhat complex.
I've got

```java
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class OrderHistoryResponseDTO(
    @Json(name = "result") val result: List<OrderHistoryDTO>?,
    @Json(name = "pagination") val pagination: PaginationDTO?,
)
```

which in turn has

```java
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class OrderHistoryDTO(
    @Json(name = "firstServiceDateTime") val firstServiceDateTime: Date?,
    @Json(name = "orderDateTime") val orderDateTime: Date?,
    @Json(name = "proposalDateTime") val proposalDateTime: Date?,
    @Json(name = "proposalDeadlineDateTime") val proposalDeadlineDateTime: Date?,
    @Json(name = "isEditable") val isEditable: Boolean?,
    @Json(name = "orderCode") val orderCode: Int?,
    @Json(name = "orderItemTypeInfo") val orderItemTypeInfo: List<TypeInfoDTO>?,
    @Json(name = "orderProposalCode") val orderProposalCode: String?,
    @Json(name = "orderType") val orderType: OrderTypeEnum?,
    @Json(name = "storeCode") val storeCode: Int?
)
```

```java
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class TypeInfoDTO (
    @Json(name = "orderItemType") val orderItemType: String?,
    @Json(name = "secondServiceDateTime") val secondServiceDateTime: Date?,
    @Json(name = "provisioningBulks") val provisioningBulks: Double?,
    @Json(name = "truckingBulks") val truckingBulks: Double?
)
```

```java
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class PaginationDTO(
    @Json(name = "offset") val offset: Int?,
    @Json(name = "count") val count: Int?,
    @Json(name = "totalResults") val totalResults: Int?
)
```

and I create the adapters as follows

```java
 val listOrdersHistoryDTO: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(
            List::class.java,
            OrderHistoryDTO::class.java
        )
        val listOrdersHistoryDTOAdapter : JsonAdapter<List<OrderHistoryDTO>> =
            Moshi.Builder().add(MoshiDateAdapter(MoshiDateAdapter.DATE_UTC)).build().adapter(listOrdersHistoryDTO)

        val listTypeInfosDTO: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(
            List::class.java,
            TypeInfoDTO::class.java
        )

        val listTypeInfosDTOAdapter : JsonAdapter<List<TypeInfoDTO>> = Moshi.Builder().add(MoshiDateAdapter(MoshiDateAdapter.DATE_UTC)).build().adapter(listTypeInfosDTO)

        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(MoshiDateAdapter(MoshiDateAdapter.DATE_UTC))
            .add(listOrdersHistoryDTO, listOrdersHistoryDTOAdapter)
            .add(listTypeInfosDTO, listTypeInfosDTOAdapter)
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(apiServerUrl)
            .build()
            .create(SupplyOrdersServices::class.java)
```

This throws me a parsing exception
Any ideas?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the exception to your question for more context.

Comment: the exception Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<com.dia.tiendas.dia_api_library.data.supply_orders_v1.remote.model.OrderHistoryResponseDTO>.
  Tried:
   * retrofit2.CompletableFutureCallAdapterFactory
   * retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory